# How to submit data to server using jquery post

Tags: jquery, json, post

I am using jquery post to submit data on server and data having json array for one of the value.

```
$.post({
type: "POST",
url: "http://someurl",
data: {
    id = 12345, order_items: [{
        "product_id": "1065",
        "sku": {
            "SKU": "RHJ",
            "msg": "In Stock"
        },
        "qty": "1"
    }]
    cup = 0, 
    rec = 0
},
```

});

Now how can I post it and get the result?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?  ASP.NET, PHP, JSP, etc?  You'll need something on the server-side to receive and process the post.

Comment: If you aren't sure how or what this "server side" and "post" stuff means, you need to take a step back and get some learning on! Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting for an overview, then choose a language. I like PHP - http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php You've got the javascript part all set, now the "http://someurl" is the important bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $>post use $.ajax request this will give you great access on control.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type : 'POST',
    data : $(this).serialize(), // this = $('#form_id') is form id
    url  : $(this).attr('action'),
    //dataType:'json',
    success : function(data)
    {
        $('#wrapper').html(data);
    }
});
```